# Webpack ui-bootstrap

Tags: webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use ui-bootstrap with Webpack, but i have problem, when i try to use something like this

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#install-with-npm

```
import accordion from 'angular-ui-bootstrap/src/accordion';
angular.module('myModule', [accordion]);
```

I am getting error
Can not find module?

Here id config

```
var loaders = require("./loaders");
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/app/main.ts'],
    output: {
        filename: 'build.js',
        path: 'dist'
    },
    resolve: {
        root: __dirname,
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
            template: './src/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Highcharts: 'highcharts'
        }),
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8081,
            server: {
                baseDir: 'dist'
            },
            ui: false,
            online: false,
            notify: false
        }),
        /*
        * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
        * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
        *
        * Copies project static assets.
        *
        * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
        */
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'src/images/favicons',
            to: 'favicons',
        }])
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: loaders
    }
};
```

Is there quick fix for this common problem?

Comment: share your webpack.config

Comment: I have update answer

Comment: Add the error details as well